# Inserting Comment and Color into a cell that satisfies If...Then Statement

Tags: vba, excel

So I am basically trying to insert a comment and color the cell that basically meets the criteria that I set in my code. I searched all over but cant seem to find a viable solution.

Here is the code that I have so far and I mentioned in the code below where I would like the color and comment to be. The way I have this macro set up is that it gets "Called" from the Worksheet. I used the Selection_Change function. So I have a range where in one column someone enters data and then whatever data is entered the following macro runs and checks to see if it is within limits.

If it is not within the limits that are set in the excel sheet ("M7" and "M19"), I would like a color to highlight that certain cell and a set comment in that cell. How would I go about this? I really appreciate the help. Thank you!

Also I found a code online and my problem is that when i use the

```
ActiveCell.AddComment ("Text")
```

I keep getting an error, and also after I enter my data point and I press enter, the comment goes into the next cell.

Here is the macro that gets called:

```
 Option Explicit
 Public Sub OutofControlRestofData()
 Dim lRow As Long
 Dim lstRow As Long
 Dim data As Variant
 Dim ul As Variant
 Dim ll As Variant
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet


With Application
 .ScreenUpdating = True
 .EnableEvents = True
 .DisplayAlerts = True

 End With

 Set ws = Sheets(2)
 ws.Select

lstRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(1, ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row)
 For lRow = 1 To lstRow
 data = Cells(lRow, "E").Value
 ul = Range("M7")
 ll = Range("M19")

 If data > ul Or data < ll Then

 If IsNumeric(data) = True And data Like "" = False Then

 MsgBox ("There was an Out of Control Point at " & Cells(lRow, "C").Value)

'THIS IS WHERE I THINK THE COMMENTING AND COLOR CODE WOULD BE

 End If
 End If

 Next lRow

End Sub
```

Also here is the code that Calls the Macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("E39:E138")) Is Nothing Then

Run ("OutofControlRestofData")

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to note.

1. You should practice using tab to "nest" your `If` statements.  Makes
   it clearer to see.
2. You can go ahead and combine the two Subs.  Just make sure you **put the code in the Sheet's code** page (not in a workbook module).
3. You don't need a loop if you already have a "`Target`" as that is the cell (Range) you want to check anyways.
4. You have defined your Change sub to only work if the data entry is between `E39` and `E138`.  Will this always be the case? Consider using the entire `column E` if you want more flexibility to grow your sheet and data.

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets(2)

If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range("E39:E138")) Is Nothing Then


    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lstRow As Long
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim ul As Variant
    Dim ll As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet


    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

    data = Target.Value
    ul = Range("M7").Value
    ll = Range("M19").Value

    If data > ul Or data < ll Then
        If IsNumeric(data) = True And data Like "" = False Then
            MsgBox ("There was an Out of Control Point at " & Target.Address)
            Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Target.AddComment ("This is an Out of Control Point")
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Works like a charm!!! Really appreciate your timely responses and quality help!

Answer (score 1):

Just to be on the safe side, I'd recommend changing your code here to include `value`:

```
data = Range("E" & lRow).Value
ul = Range("M7").Value
ll = Range("M19").Value
```

Then in the spot where you want to do the color/comment stuff:

```
Range("E" & lRow).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Range("E" & lRow).AddComment("This is an Out of Control Point")
```

Comment: Hello @Chrismas007! Thanks again for responding to my posts. I know these posts seem simple but I am completely new to vba, I started a couple of months ago and still getting the hang of things. So the above code works,but when I enter another data point. It says "Run Time error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error".

Comment: This line: Range("E" & lRow).AddComment("This is an Out of Control Point")

Comment: I was getting this type of error when I was just using ActiveCell.AddComment

Comment: You code right now is designed to loop through all the data from Row 1 to LastRow.  Would you rather this macro ran "on the condition of a data entry change"?

Comment: Yes I would rather have it run if my conditions arent met. as in it would run if the data point is either abovce the max or if its below the miniumum. I will post the code where it calls this macro above so you can see.

Comment: Check out my new answer.